# Not able to move two images using uipangesturerecogniser

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to move two images with same `UIPanGestureRecognizer` , 
I am able to move the **first** image, but as soon as I try to move the **second** image the first one goes back to its original position. I want the first image to retain it's after changed position.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(handlePanSuper:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (void)handlePanSuper:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
     static UIImageView *viewToMove;
     static CGPoint  originalCenter;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, location))
    {
        viewToMove = imageView;
        originalCenter = viewToMove.center;
    }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.image2.frame, location))
    {
        viewToMove = image2;
        originalCenter = viewToMove.center;
    }
    else
    {
        viewToMove = nil;
    }

    if (viewToMove)
    {

        viewToMove.alpha = 0.8;
        [viewToMove.superview bringSubviewToFront:viewToMove];
        NSLog(@"hi i am being touched.");
     }
 }
 if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged && viewToMove != nil)
    {
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    viewToMove.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y +                                        translation.y);


}
else if ((sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
          sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
          sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) && viewToMove != nil)
{
    // do whatever post dragging you want, e.g.
    // snap the piece into place

       // CGPoint center = viewToMove.center;
        //viewToMove.center = center;

        viewToMove.alpha  = 1.0;

        viewToMove = nil;
  }
}
```

Comment: please, give some feedback if you tried something

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your gesture recognizer in your superView. Why? You could set it inside the views that you are trying to move, it's easier and less likely to strange behaviors I edited your code, see below (not tested)

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(handlePanSuper:)];
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = self.image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    [self.image2 addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (void)handlePanSuper:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView *viewToMove = (UIImageView*)sender.view;
    CGPoint  originalCenter = viewToMove.center;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

        viewToMove.alpha = 0.8;
        [viewToMove.superview bringSubviewToFront:viewToMove];
        NSLog(@"hi i am being touched.");

    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        viewToMove.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y +                                        translation.y);

    }
    else if ((sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
          sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
          sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled))
    {
    // do whatever post dragging you want, e.g.
    // snap the piece into place

       // CGPoint center = viewToMove.center;
        //viewToMove.center = center;

        viewToMove.alpha  = 1.0;
        viewToMove = nil;
    }
}
```

Please try this, and let me know if worked.

Comment: hey man , i put this line  [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view]; , but the first image now moves a bit and then gets back to original position, ie.e first image doesnt move at all. is there a limitation that only one image can be associated with one uipangesturerecognizer function?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be no problem or limitation with the recognizer. I edited by answer, try the code above